# Do something with dns caching after transfering site to new hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, website, ns-record

I've transferred web-site to new hosting, changing ns records in domain admin panel. Everything is ok, but there is dns caching on computers visited site before. They store old ns records. Locally, problem can be solved - there are methods for clean dns cache on computer. But what to do with amount of site users? Is there any ability to initiate dns cache clean for current site or do some magic redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot force it as such.  You can take some steps to 'encourage' it however.

Check the TTL of your DNS record.  Suppose it's 1 hour. Change the TTL to 60 seconds.  Now if you wait an hour or so, any visitors hitting DNS after this will be performing a more frequent lookups and hopefully moving over to your new server.  [Read more](https://www.dnswatch.info/articles/dns-update), and be sure to change the TTL back to a higher period afterwards.

However, this is still not guaranteed - clients may *still* be using the old DNS for a while, or they may not be hitting your site for days while still maintaining their own cache.

Your actual best bet is to wait, monitor traffic on the old server, and switch it off once traffic has fallen to a trickle.

Comment: it's entirely too late to do this AFTER  the DNS change has been made. For reduced TTLs to have any affect it needed to be done  BEFORE the DNS change. Changing the TTL now will achieve nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the old server's web server software configuration, you can configure a reverse proxy on the old server, which proxies visitors' requests to your new server while DNS has been updated everywhere.

I had to do this once when I forgot to decrease DNS TTL before the migration.